# How to make certain part of an activity change depending on the day of the week?

Tags: android, kotlin, uiscrollview

I am using a HorizontalScrollView as a container, inside it I have a button for each day of the week (Monday, Tuesday..., Friday). I want that, depending on the day of the week, when opening the application, it automatically scrolls there, that is, today it is Monday the button that appears as an option is "MONDAY", if it is Wednesday the first option that appears is WEDNESDAY.

[HorizontalScrollView, contains the different buttons with different id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQpWJ.png)

[Example of how I would have to scroll if it were Wednesday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94IEh.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would get the day from the Calendar module and then use a Switch to scroll to the required position.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
switch (day) {
   case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
       scrollView.smoothScrollTo(xPosition, yPosition);
       break;
}
```